# JQuery AJAX File Download in IE8, displaying the yellow security bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page where a user can select some options on a form, the forms submit event posts this data to a PHP page through .AJAX and writes a file to a server, the PHP page then returns the file name and I use jquery.Download to prompt the user to save the file.

This works perfect in FF and Chrome, but I am receiving the dreaded yellow information bar in IE. To make matters worse, if my user selects "Download anyway" from the information bar, the page just refreshes without actually prompting the user to download the file.

I've done some searching on Stackoverflow and it doesn't appear this question has been answered.

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing this because of the difference in definition between user initiated browser events and programitically initiated browser event. Generally event that is fired as a result of jQuery binding that event to an action is considered to be programatically initiated i.e.

```
$("#myElement").click(
    function() {
        $.ajax(...);
    }
);
```

You will see this same symptom when trying to open a new tab by binding a jQuery `.click()` event to your clickable link etc.

A possible work around to your issue would be to use an event attribute in your HTML code that calls a JS function where your AJAX call is made i.e.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function submitAndDownload() {
    $.ajax(...); //form submit
    $.ajax(...); //download file
}

</script>

<button onClick="submitAndDownload();"></button>
```

This way the browser considers the event to be user initiated. You could of course nest your download ajax request inside the body of your form submission ajax request. It will depend on what you need to do. However you may see some inconsistency in your socket closure if one is nested inside the other if you have other ajax calls in the mix.

Comment: thanks that is really helpful. So do you mean actually putting an onClick on my submit button versus using a submit event handler?

Comment: How exactly is your ajax call initiated? Can you provide some code? The approach will vary depending on what it is you need to do... i.e. Event sequence etc.

Comment: I've updated my answer to hopefully shed some more light on bypassing the IE fussiness.